# ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible in web driver

Tags: testing

i am trying to add text in summer note text area but an exception is generated i have tried many method like relative and absolute xpath and class for web element but no one is working

```
Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'note-editable panel-body')]")).sendKeys("test");

/*
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='addTaskFrm']/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[3]")).sendKeys("test");
*/

/*
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[96]/div/div/form/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[3]")).sendKeys("test");
*/

    /*(WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 90);// 1 minute 
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("note-editable panel-body")));
        driver.findElement(By.className("note-editable panel-body")).sendKeys("cancel");*/
```

**HTML code for summer note is**

```
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-12 m-t-md">

    <input id="note-title" name="name" value="Cancel Task" type="hidden">

    <textarea id="modal-quick-note" class="form-control modal-description-box" name="description" rows="5" placeholder="Description" style="display: none;"></textarea>

    <div class="note-editor note-frame panel panel-default">
    <div class="note-editing-area">
    <div class="note-handle">

    <div class="note-control-selection" style="display: none;">
    <div class="note-control-selection-bg"></div>
    <div class="note-control-holder note-control-nw"></div>
    <div class="note-control-holder note-control-ne"></div>
    <div class="note-control-holder note-control-sw"></div>
    <div class="note-control-sizing note-control-se"></div>
    <div class="note-control-selection-info"></div>
    </div>

    </div>

    <textarea class="note-codable"></textarea>

    <div style="position: absolute; left: -100000px; opacity: 0;" contenteditable="true"></div>

    <div class="note-editable panel-body" style="height: 235px;" contenteditable="true">

    <p>

    <p>
```

**Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible**

Comment: The XPath selector does not matter in this case. As the exception states, you're trying to send keys to an **invisible** element, that's the actual problem. There are several workaround (make it visible, use direct JS/DOM manipulation, ...) which are described in various questions here in SO.

Comment: yes i have used js method but same error is generated ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementByClass('note-editable panel-body').value='cancelled'");